# How to avoid matching unwanted blocks in regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

How to avoid matching unwanted blocks in regex.

For example, I just want to match the static prototypes in C language and how to make it not include the main function.

```c
/**
 * @brief
 *
 * @param dsc
 */
static void func1(const char *dsc);

/**
 * @brief
 *
 * @param argc
 * @param argv
 * @return int
 */
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);

/**
 * @brief
 *
 * @param dsc
 */
static void fun2(const char *dsc);
```

my regex is

```bash
\/\*[\w\W]*?\*\/\n+^static.*\);
```

and it alway match the main function prototypes. In Vscode just like this:

[image: example]

Comment: Replace `[\w\W]*?` with `(?:(?!/\*|\*/)[\w\W])*?`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
/\*(?:(?!/\*|\*/)[\w\W])*?\*/\n+static.*\);
```

Note that you do not need to escape the `/` char in the search and replace field since the regex is defined with a mere string, not a regex literal notation where `/` chars are used as regex delimiters.

The `(?:(?!/\*|\*/)[\w\W])*?` part makes it match any char, zero or more but as few as possible times, that does not start a `/*` or `*/` char sequence.

You do not need `^` as a start of a line anchor here since it makes no sense after `\n+`, it is implied there.